# Is it possible to extend the default HyperLink in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, extend

I was to change some behaviour when the `text` attribute is set against a hyperlink. I know I can create my own version of like

```
public class MyHyperLink: System.Web.UI.Hyperlink
{
}
```

however, **is it possible to override `HyperLink` one so I don't have to use a custom HyperLink class  on the front end controls**?